# Separate Matlab Editor Module?

Tags: matlab, editor, warnings

Is it possible to have Matlab editor, without having the whole Matlab?
The warnings that Matlab editor provides are useful for me in coding, but I can not afford buying Matlab. How can I only use the editor? Does it still give warnings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [GNU Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/). Configure [Emacs Octave Support](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Emacs-Octave-Support.html). Then M files, within Emacs, will have syntax highlighting and indentation. You will not have in-editor warnings as in the MATLAB editor.

You could use Octave to run and test your M files. For simple scripts and functions, little to no modifications will be required to go from MATLAB to Octave, or vice versa. The same is not true for MATLAB code that implements GUIs or some of the more specialized toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

You could certainly use a text editor to edit matlab files, as long as you save them with the .m extension. Unfortunately, as Matlab is the only program that can interpret the file, you won't get warnings as you work.

As an alternative, you could get FreeMat (http://freemat.sourceforge.net/) and work with .m files with proper syntax highlighting. However, FreeMat does not have the vast library of functions that Matlab has, and still won't provide you with warnings as you code.

Maybe you could work with Matlab in your institution's library (if you're a student), or get your business to pay for it (if you're a professional)?

Comment: Thanks. I have access to Matlab from my institution in command line, but the GUI and editor is not available.